# I need to create methods get () and status () to create a test controller with mockmvc?

Tags: controller, spring-boot, mockmvc

I am trying to test my first controller, followed a few examples on the internet, but is in error in methods `get()` and `status()` to compile.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import br.com.boot.application.Application;
import br.com.boot.controller.ClienteController;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ClienteControllerTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private ClienteController controller;
    
    @Mock
    private MockMvc mock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mock = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testandoClienteController() throws Exception{
        this.mock.perform(get("/novo").andExpect(status().isOk()));
    }
}
```

My Class Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cliente")
public class ClienteController {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteAplicacaoService service;

    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/novo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody 
    public ClienteData novo(@RequestBody NovoClienteComando comando){
        String clienteId = service.novoCliente(comando);
        return service.obterCliente(clienteId);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/obter")
    @ResponseBody 
    public ClienteData obter(@RequestParam("clienteId") String clienteId){
        return service.obterCliente(clienteId);
    }
    
}

Error:
```

Multiple markers at this line
- The method get(String) is undefined for the type
ClienteControllerTest
- The method status() is undefined for the type
ClienteControllerTest

Comment: Well the error is correct. Not sure if Eclipse quick-fix is smart enough but you should add a couple of static imports for the class `MockMvcRequestBuilders` which contains those methods.

Answer (score 54):

Try adding the following imports:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
```

Comment: @Tiago Costa, if this answer resolve your question, would you accept it? By the way, I think it does.

Comment: This solved it for me even after 8 years. However, it wouldn't have been necessary if Spring and SpringBoot documentation showed import statements on their sample code.

Answer (score 6):

If you just need **get** and **status**, add the following

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
```